# Content not rotated when printing in wpf

Tags: wpf, printing, landscape, xps

I am printing an XPS document using the System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog. When I choose landscape orientation in the print dialog the resulting page is rotated to landscape but the actual content stays in portrait mode and is clipped.

This is the way I print. I also tried to use the AddJob method on PrintDialog.PrintQueue and the overloads on PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(...).Write(...) all with the same or worse result. And I tried to set DocumentPaginator.PageSize, the printDialog.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize and the width and height of th first FixedPage to the correct lanscape size with no result.  PrintDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation is on landscape and PrintDialog.PrintableAreaWidth and PrintDialog.PrintableAreaHeight is as it should be when lanscape is selected after the PrintDialog was shown.

```
var printDialog = new PrintDialog
        {
            MaxPage = (uint)pageCount,
            MinPage = 1,
            PageRange = new PageRange(1, pageCount),
            UserPageRangeEnabled = true
        };

if (printDialog.ShowDialog() != true) return;
using (var doc = new XpsDocument(filename, FileAccess.Read)) 
{
    var paginator = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence().DocumentPaginator;
    printDialog.PrintDocument(fds.paginator , "myPrintJob");
}
```

Comment: That sounds like the proper behavior. Unlike html for example, XPS is a fixed page format - in your case, the content is already laid out to fit on a portrait sheet of paper (tall and skinny). Switching the print ticket, or even the fixed page dimensions to a landscape (short and wide) size does not cause the content to reflow to fit because the content is fixed in place. If you want to reflow the content, you may be better off going to the content source and generating a new xps document from there, rather than trying to reflow an existing document.

Comment: I was hoping for a different answer but I quess you are right. Thanks for your comment.